# Fill with Measure/ArrangeOverride inside a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, measureoverride

I have a custom drawn control containing some plots. 
I've put it inside a scrollviewer since later I want to be able to zoom the control's contents.
I want this control to have a specific minimum height and if the available visible space is bigger than that it should fill the space.
However using MeasureOverride I just get infinity for the available height (because of the scrollviewer).
How can I get the actual available visible space during MeasureOverride to stretch my control to this height?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to do any layout overriding for that, just set the alignments to `Stretch` and a `MinHeight`.

Comment: You are right, this works. Thanks :)
However now I have the next problem:
I draw all the plots manually for performance reasons.
I also do the zooming that way and I'd like the panel to grow in height according to the zoom level (scrolling inclusive).
How can I achieve that? (The control's height is set to NaN, just tried that)

Comment: @TobiasZimmermann: Use the [`LayoutTrasform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx), set it to a [`ScaleTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work well thanks to me drawing my plots "by hand" (it looks terrible then)

Comment: @TobiasZimmermann: Well, that would have been the standard way, can't you change the size and simultaneously change the scale at which you draw?